# How to Bind Array of numbers to Range Slider using JavaScript/Jquery/Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I tried this below code:

```
<input type="range" id="slider1" min="0" max="6" step="1" value="1">
<output id="output"></output>
```

```js
var values = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128];
$('#slider1').change(function () {
    $('.slider #slider1').attr('value', values[this.value]);
    memoryslider = $('input[id="slider1"]').attr('value');
    var data = document.getElementById("output");
    data.innerText = memoryslider;
});
```

This works fine but out put showing after mouse click, But i want to output values when mouse is moving, is there any possibility please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the update of the `#output` element while the range is being dragged you should use the `input` event. You also shouldn't change the `value` attribute manually on change of the input. Try this:

```js
var values = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128];
$('#slider1').on('change input', function() {
  var value = values[this.value];
  $("#output").text(value);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="slider1" min="0" max="6" step="1" value="1">
<output id="output"></output>
```

Also note that as all your values are powers of 2 you can use the `Math.pow()` method instead of hard-coding the values in to an array:

```js
$('#slider1').on('change input', function() {
  var value = Math.pow(2, +this.value + 1);
  $("#output").text(value);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="slider1" min="0" max="6" step="1" value="1">
<output id="output"></output>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan,,,

Comment: No problem, glad to help